# React-router does not seem to render the next page when implementing headless e2e test using Nightwatch/Cucumber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cucumber, e2e-testing

I am trying to implement a headless e2e test using nightwatch, Cucumber and nightwatch-cucumber (deprecated - will probably use a different e2e after this but for now I have to get it to work) on my React app. Everything works fine locally, but when I run headless, it either does not load the next page, or css selector is not working. I am strongly thinking it is the first.

I am kinda running into a block trying to debug. Any other methods of debugging will be greatly appreciated. Other than running the testing script again after changing the nightwatch.config file and trying out different css selector, I do not know what else to do.

```
//test devDependencies
"devDependencies": {
   "chai": "^3.5.0",
   "cucumber": "^4.0.0",
   "cucumber-pretty": "^1.4.0",
   "dotenv": "^5.0.1",
   "https-proxy-agent": "^2.2.1",
   "nightwatch": "^0.9.19",
   "nightwatch-cucumber": "^9.1.0",
   "selenium-server": "^3.9.1",
   "wait-on": "^2.1.0"
}

// nightwatch.config
const seleniumServer = require('selenium-server');
require('dotenv').config({ path: `.env_${process.env.NODE_ENV || `local`}` })
require('nightwatch-cucumber')({
  cucumberArgs: [
    '--require', 'step-definitions',
    '--format', 'node_modules/cucumber-pretty',
    '--format', 'json:reports/test-results.json',
    'features']
});

// Determines if the local enviornment is local or jenkins
const env = process && process.env && process.env.NODE_ENV || `local`;
console.log(`~!~!~!~! ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`)

module.exports = {
    "output_folder": "reports",
    "selenium": {
        "start_process": true,
        "server_path": seleniumServer.path,
        "log_path": "",
        "port": 9876,
        "cli_args": {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": env === `local` 
                ? `./chromedriver` 
                : `/usr/bin/chromedriver`
        }
    },
    "test_settings": {
        // Used as default
        "default": {
            "selenium_port": 9876,
            "selenium_host": "localhost",
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "acceptSslCerts": true, 
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
                "chromeOptions": {
                  "args": [
                      "--headless",
                      "disable-web-security",
                      "ignore-certificate-errors",
                      "no-sandbox",
                      "disable-gpu"
                  ]
                }
            }
        },
        // Used for local chrome browser testing
        "local": {
            "selenium_port": 9876,
            "selenium_host": "localhost",
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
                "chromeOptions": {
                  "args": [
                      "disable-web-security",
                      "ignore-certificate-errors",
                      "no-sandbox",
                      "disable-gpu",
                      "window-size=1440,900"
                  ]
                }
            }
        },
        // Used for PR build pipeline
        "build": {
            "selenium_port": 9876,
            "selenium_host": "localhost",
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
                "chromeOptions": {
                  "args": [
                      "headless",
                      "disable-web-security",
                      "ignore-certificate-errors",
                      "no-sandbox",
                      "disable-gpu",
                      "window-size=1440,900"
                  ]
                }
            }
        },
        // Used for Regression
        "redblu": {
            "selenium_port": 8080,
            "selenium_host": "bluxpress-sts.clouddqt.capitalone.com",
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName" : "chrome",
                "recordVideo" : true,
                "name" : "aviator-ui-test",
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
                "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "chromeOptions": {
                    "args": [
                        "ignore-certificate-errors",
                        "disable-gpu",
                        "no-sandbox",
                        "start-maximized"
                    ]
                  }
            }
        }
  }
};
```

I have this setup but when I run nightwatch with headless, it fails. Everything works locally tho. Does it not support macos at the time?